# Can I use the binomial theorem to expand (1+n)^n?

Tags: binomial-theorem

Would it be $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} n^k$ ?

Comment: Yes,  that is correct.

Comment: Yes you can! It is correct

Comment: Yes that's true. You can also write it as $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}n^{n-k}$$

Comment: Sort of like $$64 = 4^3 = (1 + 3)^3 = \binom{3}{0}3^0 + \binom{3}{1}3^1 + \binom{3}{2}3^2 + \binom{3}{3}3^3.$$

Comment: Show the work and why would it night be that.

Comment: The binomial expansion for $(a+b)^n$ works for all $a,b$, so it must also work for $a=1, b=n$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. It's completely correct. $n$ is just a fixed number here.
(just to be able to close the question)